# What documents does a sponsor in the UK have to show in order to confirm they can host a guest?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

Provided that my sponsor owns a house in the UK, are council tax and utility bills enough documents as proof that my sponsor can accommodate me?

Comment: This might help http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25464/do-i-need-to-provide-any-documents-for-my-friends-uk-visa-application?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

No.

---

[GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) provides guidance about documentation to support a visa application. Note in particular *All documents must be originals and not photocopies* and Section 4:
**Section 4: documents you should not send unless specifically requested**

> This page provides guidance on the types of documents that are not required to consider your application.
>
> •  if you are applying as a family/group you do not need to provide multiple copies of the same documents
> •   bank statements or letters issued more than 1 year before the date of application
> •   driving licence
> •   photographs (other than passport photographs required in section 1)
> •   notarial certificates
> •   business cards
> •   hotel bookings
> •   flight bookings
> •   photocopies of bank cards
> •   credit card statements
> •   certificates relating to leisure activities
> •   evidence of car ownership
> •   travel insurance
> •   **sponsor’s utility bills**
> •   **sponsor’s council tax bills**
> •   educational certificates (unless specifically listed in section 3)

I have emboldened the two you ask about.

**Section 2: other documents you may want to provide – all visitors** covers what may strengthen your case. This includes, from sponsors:

> where a third party (who is either in the UK or who will be legally in the UK at the time of your visit) is providing financial support to you e.g. a business, a friend or a relative, documents to show they have sufficient resources to support you in addition to themselves and any dependant family should be provided